# Where is the "Service Configuration" of Azure stored?

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-cloud-services

I'm creating a build server for Azure cloud services.
It fails with the message:

> " C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows
>   Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(373,5): error WAT200:
>   No default service configuration "ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" could be
>   found in the project".

When the project is compiled locally everything is fine and the correct configuration is picked up.

When I change the Service Configuration inside the Development Tab of the Project  Properties the build picks up the correct configuration locally.

The question is what is the exact storage for the "Service Configuration" option and how can I propagate it to the build server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the value that you specified for the **TargetProfile** property, which corresponds to the configuration selected for packaging or deployment. And please make sure if the service configuration file that you specified in the TargetProfile property is included in your source folder. Besides, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery) to know more about how to build package using MSBuild.